# How to reset VSTS counter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a need to reset VSTS counter. I do not see any way to do this through UI. There is a way to do it by directly invoking [reset build counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/reset%20counter?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) REST API, but in order to do this, you need to know the counter id, which you should be able to find out by invoking [get a definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) REST API. Unfortunately, no matter what I do [get a definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) call does not return [build definition counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#builddefinitioncounter).

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you use own variable?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=yaml

Comment: I do. But I still need the ability to reset build counter.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Dallamura from Microsoft wrote [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/364140/azure-devops-api-version-41-does-not-return-buildd.html) thread:

> the counters feature was experimental and removed back in March of
>   this year. I'm not sure how it even got into the documentation, but
>   I'll make sure it gets cleaned up.

I also didn't success to get the `counterId` in an API call.

At workaround, you can reset the revision of the build number if you change the build definition name, you can just add/remove a character.

Comment: What do you mean by "revision of the build number"?

Comment: The "counter" - the `$(Rev:.r)` variable in the build number.

Comment: $(Rev:.r) is reset every day.

Comment: No, if in the build name there is a date (`$(date:yyyyMMdd)`) so it will reset every day, if not (and the build number stay static) the revision will not reset. So what is your question? which counter do you want to reset?

Comment: 1. We have a date in build number. This is why we use custom counters.

2. I need to be able to reset custom counter. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#counters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to reset the counter variable, you could create a new variable with a GUID prefix.

This solution creates duplicate counters which might not be ideal but this gives you the ability to revert back to the previous counter values, if necessary.

Please see the following YAML code snippet

```
variables: 
  ...
  #Change this Guid if you require a reset seed on the same value.
  resetCounterGuid: 'efa9f3f5-57fb-4254-8a7a-06d5bb365173'
  buildrevision: $[counter(format('{0}\\{1}',variables['resetCounterGuid'],variables['YOUR_DEFINED_VARIABLE']),0)]
 ...
```