# Reset DevOps custom counter variable back to 0

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Having some difficulty retrieving `counterId={counterId}`
in the following API method:

```
https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?counterId={counterId}&api-version=4.1
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/reset%20counter?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1

I am trying to retrieve the counterId in order to reset it.
Is there any way to retrieve the counterId?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset VSTS counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164873/how-to-reset-vsts-counter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve found a solution.
I can reset the counter by prefixing the custom variable.
Also if using a custom variable e.g $[counter(001)], to reset the counter increment the custom variable to $[counter(002)]

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with microsoft Api for resetting the counter, Here is the ticket problem that is still perssit till this time writting this comment https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/provide-a-working-api-or-other-way-to-reset-counte/1080394

Comment: also I want to add something maybe It can help someone, you can reset the variable back to another value by using this syntax: `$[counter(01,42)]` then if it keeps incrementing and you want to reset it again you can increment the first variable like this `$[counter(02,42)]`, this baiscly means that the counter depends on the first parameter (variable actually) `01` if it changed the counter will be reseted to its default value `42`, Hope I was clear.