# Is there still no way to reset the counter in the Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use the old Azure Pipeline (with UI, no yaml) with a self-hosted agent. In order to version my project I did the following: I declared two variables on the tab "Variables" named `Major` and `Minor`. Then I declared the variable `Revision` with the following value: `$[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']),11)]` (you may ask why the revision starts with 11. That is simply the prerequisite for my project, I cannot change it). Finally, I declared the variable named `Version` with the value `$(Major).$(Minor).$(Revision).0`.

Summarized (the values ​​for major and minor were chosen at random):

```
Major = 1
Minor = 2
Revision = $[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']),11)]
Version = $(Major).$(Minor).$(Revision).0
```

The code above means that the version is incremented starting with the number 11 for the `Revision`:

```
1.2.11.0 // first run
1.2.12.0 // second run
1.2.13.0 // third run
and so on
```

The question is: How can I force the pipeline to reset the value that was saved for the counter? I already tried to delete `Revision` and `Version` (and thus also the counter), tried to delete the `.json` file with the settings for the current pipeline, but it seems to have nothing to do with the counter value. The only thing that helped me was the cloned version of the pipeline. For this cloned version the counter is set to 11 again.

Of course, I have seen [How to reset VSTS counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164873/how-to-reset-vsts-counter). Unfortunately, I cannot use the proposed solution. In addition, the mentioned question is relatively old and I thought someone might have found another solution.

Comment: The counter is just an incremental number started from 11? if yes, why you need this - `format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']` in the counter?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk you are right, I actually don't need them. These variables exist in the .ps1 script that was involved in this story with the version incrementing, now I want get rid of this script and I just transferred everything "one to one" to Azure. But yes, I not really need Major and Minor variables (until my chief says the opposite). Would deleting these two variables solve the problem?

Comment: yes, instead of them put there `counter` for example, now, each time you will change the `counter` name it will be rested.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk now I understand what you probably meant in your first answer to the question "How to reset VSTS counter?". Nice workaround. But I leave my question open, maybe someone from Microsoft writes here their own opinion to this old but still very current problem.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? is it worked for you?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, it worked fine. @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, it worked fine. But it is still a workaround. I don't reset the counter to 11. Instead, I declare a new counter that is associated with the value of the variable that is in the first position in `format(...)`.

Comment: you're right, because i think it's impossible to reset the current counter :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no default way to reset the counter yet. You may submit a suggestion at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Done: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1080394/provide-a-working-api-or-other-way-to-reset-counte.html#

Comment: Currently, you can use the workaround that Shayki Abramczyk provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.yml-File:
variables:
  run: $[counter(1)] // will increase with every run
```

reset-Counter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/reset-counter?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-4.1

I have to admit, I haven't tested the reset-Counter-API yet, will need it someday and can post back then.

Comment: I think I've already seen this solution and if I remember correctly, I couldn't find the CounterId.
```POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?counterId={counterId}&api-version=4.1```
And honestly, I don't know, what ```definitionId``` should be.

Comment: If you call the API to get a build definition, you'll get the "BuildDefinitionCounter" and inside, there the counter ID

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#builddefinitioncounter

Comment: update:
found this, thank you M$ again
"the counters feature was experimental and removed back in March of this year. I'm not sure how it even got into the documentation, but I'll make sure it gets cleaned up. Sorry for the confusion."

Answer (score 1):

Universal solution:

1. Create variables for your pipeline:

```
Major = 1
Minor = 2
Patch = $[counter(format('{0}.{1}',variables['Major'], variables['Minor']),0)]
```

2. Edit you azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
trigger:
- main


steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your commands here!
      echo $(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)
```

Patch counter resets whenever either Major or Minor value changes.

3. Adopt the solution for your needs.

Comment: It is not the solution but a workaround! You are doing exactly what I suggest in my question. More precisely, I didn't suggest that, it's a meanwhile old and well-known workaround. In this case, a new counter is always created. Microsoft should extend the API for counter resetting. The feature request is hear since almost two years, but they don't care: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1080394/provide-a-working-api-or-other-way-to-reset-counte.html#

Comment: In other words you do `$[counter(format('{0}',variables['Token']),1)]` and, we say, the `Token` is `31.01.2022-0`. If I change the `Token` to whatever, it will also create a new counter starting at 1 again. But the old one is no longer reachable! If I change the `Token` back to `31.01.2022-0`, then I can reach the old counter again.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround after tried your counter like so

```
$[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']),0)]
```

when I want to reset to 0 manualy, I just had some random stuff in the format string.

Here as a variable.

```
$[counter(format('{0}{1}.{2}', 'R1', variables['Major'], variables['Minor']),0)]
```

It's a new counter.

Comment: Yes, this is a known workaround. I've been using a similar approach to "reset" the counter for more than two years. It is not actually reset, but the overwriting, maybe even a creation of a new counter. Everything I can say: Microsoft hasn't done anything to fix this for more than two years (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/provide-a-working-api-or-other-way-to-reset-counte/1080394).